# What's the point of arguments for #references method in ActiveRecord::QueryMethods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I don't understand the point of `*table_names` argument in the definition of ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#references method.

I've read the Rails Guide about Query Interface and can't understand why do we need to use any table names. It seems that this method perfectly works with anything that you pass to it.

```
User.includes(:posts).where("posts.name = 'foo'").references(:posts)
```

Has same effect as:

```
User.includes(:posts).where("posts.name = 'foo'").references(:abcd)
User.includes(:posts).where("posts.name = 'foo'").references(nil)
User.includes(:posts).where("posts.name = 'foo'").references(123)
User.includes(:posts).where("posts.name = 'foo'").references('anything you want')
```

I think that if we have argument `*table_names` then there gotta be some difference between putting actual table names and other things we can put?

Comment: I'm guessing that when you use `#includes` and `#references` together its actually delegating to `#eager_load` instead which does not take `#references` into account. Its definatly a deviation from what the documented behaviour should be.

Comment: I looked into the source code of activerecord and found some funny thing. The method `#references_eager_loaded_tables?` is one of the methods that decide whether to use eager_loading or not. And in the end it does it this way: `(references_values - joined_tables).any?`, where `references_values` are basically arguments you passed to `#references`. So yeah, you can give anything, and activerecord will bend to use eager loading. Thanks for good suggestion!

Comment: One of the biggest problems with `#includes` is that its too smart for its own good. It usually does the right thing - but it can be really difficult to guess what its actually going to do query wise in more complex cases. If I know upfront that i'm going to use the joined records I always use `#eager_load` instead.

Comment: In addition to what @max said. If you are going to use the joined records AND you are going to base a query condition on them then you should use `joins(:posts).includes(:posts)` this enforces the inclusion of the join table as well as creates an INNER JOIN which will be more efficient than an OUTER JOIN. (An OUTER JOIN with a where condition on the joined table is an INNER JOIN except in the case of `where join_table.column IS NULL`)